# Microsoft SQL ignore ÅÄÖ and instead use the corresponding English words

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have in table varchar name = 'härligt'.
How can I find that record if my query is like: where name = 'harligt' ? 
It should ignore ÅÄÖ and instead use the corresponding English words.

Comment: Use an accent-insensitive collation: `WHERE Name = 'harligt' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI`. If you do this "all the time", give your column or even your entire database this collation.

Comment: Thank you ! It worked perfectly

Comment: @JeroenMostert That should be the answer instead of the comment, as it is the right thing to do.

Comment: @Apokralipsa: often but not always, depending on your database and your existing indexes and the performance this query needs. I prefer leaving a quick comment if I don't want to take the time to write up an answer that meets my standards (as in this case). If you think it suffices as-is, feel free to make an answer. (Don't forget to search for a dupe first -- I haven't done *that* either.)